Вывести элементы списка чисел через пробел
Помогите разобраться! Нужно вывести элементы списка чисел через пробел, а не через запятую.
a = int(input("Введите первое число: "))
b = int(input("Введите второе число: "))
numbers = []
for number in range(a, b + 1):
    if (a <= b) and (number % 2 == 0):
        numbers.append(number)
print(numbers)

Введите первое число: 1
Введите второе число: 10
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
Process finished with exit code 0

как задать хороший вопрос

print (*numbers) попробуйте

Супер. Сработало!! Спасибо!

a = int(input()); b = int(input()); print(*range(a + a % 2, b + 1, 2))

@stanislav-volodarskiy, спасибо. Я пока так сокращать не умею. Возьму на заметку!

В комментариях дали хороший ответ: print(*numbers). Разберём что и как здесь вообще происходит:
Функция print(obj) выводит в консоль содержимое объекта obj. Так как obj содержит в себе не строку функции print приходится преобразовывать его к ней вызывая obj.__str__(). По умолчанию для списков он возвращает его строковое представление в формате [1, 2, 3].
При вызове print(*arr) мы распаковываем массив arr, иными словами:
print(*[1, 2, 3])
# аналогично записи
print(1, 2, 3)

При передаче нескольких значений в print он приводит каждое из данных значений к строке и выводит, разделяя их параметром sep, который по умолчанию равен пробелу. Его так же можно поменять:
# end указывает, чем заканчивается строка, по умолчанию - \n
print(1, 2, 3, sep='; ', end='.\n') # -> 1; 2; 3.


Благодарю. Ваш комментарий записал себе в конспект. Очень доступно объяснили, спаисбо

Оказалось проще, чем я думал.
Спасибо @CrazyElf
a = int(input("Введите первое число: "))
b = int(input("Введите второе число: "))
numbers = []
for number in range(a, b + 1):
    if (a <= b) and (number % 2 == 0):
        numbers.append(number)
print(*numbers) # нужно было добавить '*' перед 'numbers'


Я сейчас напишу ответ, где поясню почему и как это работает

Да, напишите, пожалуйста. Очень буду признателен!
